# Systemd - path is not absolute - cannot execute

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd

I am using Linux. I have access to the root for my user.

```
root@marais:~# pwd
/root
```

In this directory I have the following:

```
root@marais:~# ls
example.log  log_watcher.service  log_watcher.sh
```

**log_watcher.service**

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Unit]
Description=Log Watcher Service

[Service]
ExecStart=log_watcher.sh
```

**log_watcher.sh**

```
# File to output to
ErrorLogFile="./error.log"
# File to read from
ExampleLogFile="./example.log"


if [ ! -e "$ErrorLogFile" ]; then   # check if file exists
    echo "Creating error file $ErrorLogFile"
    touch $ErrorLogFile
fi

echo "copying error messages from $ExampleLogFile to $ErrorLogFile"
# copy from one file to the other
 ### Challenge 1 ###
# grep ERROR $ExampleLogFile > $ErrorLogFile 
 ### Challenge 2 ###
# tail -f $ExampleLogFile | grep --line-buffered  ERROR | tee $ErrorLogFile 
while :; do grep ERROR $ExampleLogFile > $ErrorLogFile; sleep 2; done

echo "done"
```

I run the following:

```
systemctl enable log_watcher
```

This seemed to work successfully, because I had messaged of it setting up symlinks.

Now when I try start the service:

```
systemctl start log_watcher
```

Nothing seems to happen, i.e. the `log_watcher.sh` is not called.

So when I get the status:

```
systemctl status log_watcher
```

It says that the `log_watcher.sh` is not called with an absolute path.

```
root@marais:~# systemctl status log_watcher
● log_watcher.service - Log Watcher Service
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-10-18 10:49:32 CEST; 9min ago
 Main PID: 2850 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Oct 18 10:49:32 marais systemd[1]: Started Log Watcher Service.
Oct 18 10:49:32 marais systemd[1]: log_watcher.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Oct 18 10:49:32 marais systemd[1]: log_watcher.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 18 10:49:32 marais systemd[1]: log_watcher.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 18 10:50:12 marais systemd[1]: [/root/log_watcher.service:8] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: log_watcher.sh
Oct 18 10:50:12 marais systemd[1]: log_watcher.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
Warning: log_watcher.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
```

When I run:

```
root@marais:~# readlink -f log_watcher.sh
/root/log_watcher.sh
```

It shows that my absolute path is `/root/`, and this is the path I have defined in `log_watcher.service`:

```
ExecStart=/root/log_watcher.sh
```

Question

Please can you advise how I can get this service to start and execute the `log_watcher.sh`.

Thank you

Comment: The original problem is in the title: "path is not absolute". grawity's answer is the solution. Your edit introduces a *totally different* problem. These should be two separate questions.

Comment: Your edit in fact admits qrawity's answer was right. I did a rollback to the original version of the question. Please take our short [tour] and from now on stick to the "one issue -- one question" rule. Do not change the scope of a question after it gets an answer (a good answer in particular).

Answer (score -1):

In the .service file, I needed to add `/bin/bash` before the path to the script.

For example, for backup.service:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash /root/log_watcher.sh
```

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it doesn't solve the original problem. The later issue should be a separate question (and then this answer would be a valid answer to it). Additionally your solution diverts attention from the script itself where the real problem is. It probably works but smells too much like [voodoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voodoo_programming). Most likely the shebang is wrong. By explicitly invoking `/bin/bash` you make the shebang not matter.